# Counting number of index in array using for loop

Tags: java

So I have an array from 0-4, that has 5 random integer values (ie 10,20,25,15,50). The program ask the user to enter an integer, lets say user enter 17. The program will check and with the 5 values from the array i have and print out numbers that are larger than what the user put in, in this case which is 17(I use a for loop to do this). I also want to print out the number of numbers that are larger than what the user enter, in this case 2 (numbers that are larger than 17). How do i do this? Do i write a for loop inside the first for loop?

```
int[] myArrays = new int[10,20,25,15,50];

int numEntered;

for (i = 0; i < myArrays.length; i++)
{
    if (myArrays[i] > numEntered)
        System.out.println(myArrays[i]);
}
```

Now how can I get the total numbers that are larger than what the user had input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a running total counter.

```
int counter = 0;
```

Then whenever you find a number that's larger than what the user had input, increment the counter using `counter++;`. Then after your for loop just print out the counter's value.

That should be enough information for you to solve the homework, without revealing too much.

Comment: do i set the int counter=0 before the for loop or inside the for loop?

Comment: Before the for loop. Since if you put it inside the for loop, everything inside there gets executed each iteration of the loop. Meaning if you had counter = 0, every iteration, the counter would reset to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track; basically, the problem boils down to these items:

1. Looping through your array
2. Recording items greater than your specified value
3. Summing all items encountered greater than your specified value.

You can accomplish this all with a single loop of your array.

Comment: That's what im thinking but im a little confused, do i make another for loop inside of the first for loop?

Comment: What would your other loop be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Is a second for loop required? why? I'd do it like so..

```
  //Take in the number to test.
 public void islarger(int num){
   int counter = 0;
   int numbers[] = new int[5];
   //loop through array
   for(int x=0; x < array.length; ++x){
       if(array[x] > num){
          //If it meets the condition add it to the new array
          numbers[y] = array[x];
          ++y;
       }
   }
   //print our results.
   System.out.println("There are " + counter " numbers larger than " + num + \n "They are...");
   Arrays.toString(numbers);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have an integer that you increment everytime you find a value greater than the user input?

```
int count=0;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    if(myArrays[i] > numEntered) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(myArrays[i]);
    }
}
System.out.println("found " + count + " values greater than " + numEntered);
```